# how to get current date in"MMM-YY" format using JSTL only

Tags: jstl

i want a var containing current date in above specified format using 
Kindly help.

finding solutions from previous questions, I would also avoid using

Answer (score 1):

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${currentDate}" pattern="MMM-yy" var="currentDateAsString"/>
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html.